# how can read from Firebase Real Time without using addChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

in my case when login to the application
need to get user profile from realTime Database by UID

in docs must be using addValueEventListener to read from RealTime DB

//how can get value direct from real-time firebase if I have id for obj

```
fun loginByEmail(email: String, password: String) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                getUserValueFromDB(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid, email)
            }

        }
    }
```

//My problem is here is not access to this method

```
private fun getUserValueFromDB(uid: String, email: String) { //todo
        databaseReference.child("Users").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                    var data = snap.getValue(User::class.java)
                    if (data?.id == uid) {
                        prefs.userImage = data.image!!
                        GlobalScope.launch {
                            _loginStatus.emit(true)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the data from one specific user from your database, you can do so by [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

```
private fun getUserValueFromDB(uid: String, email: String) {
    var query = databaseReference.child("Users").orderByChild("id").equalTo(uid)
    query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            ...
```

The rest of your code can stay the same, you'll just be loading a lot less data.